# Reading EXIF data from Image picked with UIImagePickerController post iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, exif

I want to read EXIF data from an image that I pick with UIImagePickerController, especially the dateTimeOriginal.

I managed to extract the data for new images taken by camera with the following code:

```
if let meta = info[.mediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary
{
    if let exif = meta [kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as? NSDictionary
    {
        if let dateTimeOriginal = exif[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal as String] as? String
        {
            print (dateTimeOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

I eventually also managed to extract the data for already existing images from the photo library with the following code:

```
if let al = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as? URL
{
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [al], options: nil)
    let asset = result.firstObject
    print (asset?.creationDate)
}
```

Everything else I tried resulted in an empty timestamp.

Unfortunately the `.referenceURL` key and the `PHAsset.fetchAssets` method are depreceated in iOS 11.0 and XCode recommends to use PHPicker instead.
PHPicker is iOS 14+ though. So I have to wonder how I am supposed to do this in iOS 11 - 13. My app has iOS 11.0 as minimum requirement.

Any other way to read the dateTimeOriginal from existing images that I might have missed (and I think I have browsed every post for this topic here) ?

Comment: Get the image data and use the ImageIO framework.

Comment: Tried that already. Unfortunately most of the exif information is empty then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally:

```
if let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset
{
    if let date = asset.creationDate
    {
            ...
    }
            
    if let location = asset.location
    {
            ...
    }
}
```

Actually it is so easy if you know what to do.